# Cant echo a string in multidimensional array but can print_r

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've run into a weird problem, I can `print_r()` my variable and it produces the following:

```
print_r($_SESSION['userdata']);

outputs: Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [username] => admin [firstname] => carl [lastname] => wirkus [password] => password [admin] => 1 [staff] => 0 [tenant] => 0 [email] => test@test.com )
```

However when I try to echo the username with:

```
echo "You are currently logged in as: " . $_SESSION['userdata']['username'] . "<br>";

outputs: You are currently logged in as:
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Don't you see? In your case it will be **$_SESSION['userdata'][0]['username']**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks closer at your `print_r($_SESSION['userdata']);`. It's an array *inside of an array*. So you're not going deep enough to reach your values.

```
echo "You are currently logged in as: " . $_SESSION['userdata'][0]['username'] . "<br>";
```